# learning (embedded) electronics

Tags: electronics

I am an aerospace engineer (currently in grad school) and I really want to get into (embedded) electronics.
But I have this problem:
I understand the theory fairly well, I took an edX course in circuits and had no problem. I can build projects from the internet. However, I have a very hard hard time connecting the theory with the practical part, understanding why projects are done the way they are done and I have a hard time to design my own projects!

Please help!

I'd appreciate the following:
-General tips: how did you learn it? How is your workflow? What should I do? Which steps should I take?
-Books: which hands on books and websites can you recommend? I am looking for books and website that are practical but also explain the why
-Kits: What kits can you recommend that combine the theory with the practical?
-Anything you think is important

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You mentioned edX. There is an [embedded systems course](https://www.edx.org/course/utaustinx/utaustinx-ut-6-01x-embedded-systems-1172) starting on 22nd January

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out, but I think I will still have to problem of translating theory into practice

Comment: Please don't ask the same question on [multiple stack exchange sites](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21246535/42473). If you accidentally ask on the wrong site, it can be migrated to the correct one.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* ilhan_garou, but questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.